# How to check a check-box and click on button, based on entity email value by Selenium & Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I have a table that contains an "email" column. any email, in the column is unique (which means the email can not duplicate).
in any row, I have a checkbox. once I check the checkbox, I got an "eye" icon that I want to click on it. I want a generic method that gets a string (could be "emaiLValue")  and then check and click on the "eye" icon'.
Both check-box and the "eye" elements - are list elements (when I inspect them - I got a list of 25, in my case).
Thanks for your assistance!
I attached a screenshot

[image]

I try to use in method like this one:

```
public void selectValueFromList(String element, String textValue) {
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(element));
    for (WebElement el : list) {
        getWaitForElement(el);
        if (el.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(textValue)) {
            click(el);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the bottom line - I want send the email to the function and expect to see that the checkbox were checked and then clicking on the "eye" icon (the clicking should open a new browser tab)